# Cannot display Task CompletedDateTime in a related list component

Tags: customer-community, tasks, related-list, activities

I have a custom object with the Activity History related list on its page layout in a customer community.

I wanted to display [`CompletedDateTime`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm?search_text=task) for Tasks that appear in this list, but the field doesn't seem to be available to include in the related list. Instead, I created a new formula(Date/Time) field on the Activity object that is simply as follows:

```
CompletedDateTime
```

*Treat blank fields as blanks*

The formula seems to work as it displays the `CompletedDateTime` value for closed Task records on the Task page layout. However, when displayed on the related list or Task list view, the value is always blank. I've verified field level security is set so that all profiles are able to see this field.

Should I abandon this approach and write the `Task.CompletedDateTime` in a trigger to a custom field instead of a formula?